# @MockClass is not working

Tags: java, testing, mocking, testng, jmockit

I am new to jmockit and trying to execute the following online example.

The @MockClass is not working. My BookStore's getBookTitle() method is calling the function of orginal class instead of the mock class.

**BookStore class:**

```
public class BookStore {

  public String getBookTitle(String isbn){
    return BookStoreService.getBookTitle(isbn);
  }
}
```

**BookStoreService class:**

```
public class BookStoreService {

  public static String getBookTitle(String isbn){
    return "Random";
  }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
public class BookStoreTest {

  private static Map<String, String> bookMap = new HashMap<String, String>(2);

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() {
    System.out.println("in setup()");
    bookMap.put("0553293354", "Foundation");
    bookMap.put("0836220625", "The Far Side Gallery");
  }

  @MockClass(realClass = BookStoreService.class)
  public static class MockBookstoreService {
    @Mock
    public static String getBookTitle(String isbn) {
        System.out.println("in getBookTitle()");
        if (bookMap.containsKey(isbn)) {
            return bookMap.get(isbn);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetBookTitle() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("in testGetBookTitle()");
    final String isbn = "0553293354";
    final String expectedTitle = "Foundation";
    BookStore store = new BookStore();
    String title = store.getBookTitle(isbn);
    System.out.println(title); // This prints "Random" instead of "Foundation"
    Assert.assertEquals(title, expectedTitle);
  }


}
```

PS: I am using TestNG

Comment: @MockClass annotation is depricated, which version of jmockit do you use?

Comment: 0.999.2. I know it is deprecated. Searching for other alternatives as well.

Comment: I would recommend you to start using Dependency Injection. One of it's benefits is much simpler testing. In this particular case you would inject BookStoreService into BookStore.

Comment: No, i'm talking about SW development general principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [latest stable version of jmockit](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jmockit/jmockit/1.15) you could do it like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    System.out.println("in setup()");
    bookMap.put("0553293354", "Foundation");
    bookMap.put("0836220625", "The Far Side Gallery");

    new MockUp<BookStoreService>() {            
        @Mock
        public String getBookTitle(String isbn) {
            System.out.println("in getBookTitle()");
            if (bookMap.containsKey(isbn)) {
                return bookMap.get(isbn);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Remove the obsolete block:

```
 public static class MockBookstoreService{...}
```